# SAXParser with android

Tags: android, xml-parsing, saxparser

i need a help in my project ,i have a web service which it return a XML response like this :

```
  <ads>
    <id>6</id>
    <lnk>http://www.nkahtani.com/</lnk>
  </ads>
```

i use SAXParser to parse the elements and this is my code

**AdvParser.java**

```
   public class AdvParser extends DefaultHandler{


String elementValue = null;
Boolean elementOn = false;
public static AdvList sitesList = null;

public static AdvList getSitesList() {
    return sitesList;
}

public static void setSitesList(AdvList sitesList) {
    AdvParser.sitesList = sitesList;
}


@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.startElement(uri, localName, qName, attributes);

    elementOn=true;
    if (localName.equals("ads"))
    {
        sitesList = new AdvList();
    } else if (localName.equals("id")) {

    }

}

    @Override
     public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
    throws SAXException {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.endElement(uri, localName, qName);
elementOn = false;

/** 
 * Sets the values after retrieving the values from the XML tags
 * */ 
if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("id"))
    sitesList.setId(elementValue);
else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("lnk"))
    sitesList.setLink(elementValue);

    }

    @Override
      public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
    throws SAXException {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.characters(ch, start, length);
if (elementOn) {
    elementValue = new String(ch, start, length);
    Log.i("XMLParser", elementValue);
    elementOn = false;
}

 }
  }
```

**AdvList.java**

```
 public class AdvList {

private ArrayList<String> link = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> id = new ArrayList<String>();


public ArrayList<String> getLink() {
    return link;
}
public void setLink( String link) {
    this.link .add(link);
}
public ArrayList<String> getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id .add(id);
}
  }
```

**and this to call the URL**

```
    public class RegisterTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer,  String> {
    ProgressDialog dialog;

       protected String doInBackground(Void... N) {
         publishProgress(0);
        try {
            //Result = LoginRequest();


            SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader xmlReader=saxParser.getXMLReader();
            AdvParser handler = new AdvParser(); 
             xmlReader.setContentHandler(handler);
            URL url = new URL("http://82.192.79.39:9000/api/ads/get");
            HttpURLConnection connection =        (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            is = connection.getInputStream();

            xmlReader.parse(new InputSource(is));
            //saxParser.parse(is, handler);
            //Log.i("Pars", handler.getNameAtt() +"  "+handler.getNameAtt());

                // TODO Auto-generated catch block

     return "hi";
            } 
            catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                  return null;
            }       
       }
       @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        if(progress[0] == 0)
        {
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(SplashScreen.this, "Please wait", 
                       "Login ,Please wait.", true);
               super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
        }
       }
       protected void onPostExecute(InputStream result) {


         dialog.dismiss();
       }
   }
```

i don't have any exception in my code but the problem is that i don't get any result and the parser parse only the first tag (ads) and didn't read the other tags (id,lnk)
could any one tell me how to solve it

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue some time back, what worked for me was that i used a different boolean for all tags and a different StringBuilder for all tag values. Here are some minor modifications to your handler.

```
public static final String ID = "id";
public static final String LINK = "lnk";
Boolean bool_id, bool_link,flag;
StringBuilder out_id,out_link;
Boolean elementOn = false;

public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("ads")) {
        flag = true;
    }
    if (flag) {
        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase(ID)) {
            out_id= new StringBuilder();
            elementOn = true;
            bool_id= true;
        } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase(LINK)) {
            out_link = new StringBuilder();
            elementOn = true;
            bool_link = true;
        }
    }
}

public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {
    if (elementOn) {
        if (bool_id)
            out_id.append(new String(ch, start, start + length));
        else if (bool_link)
            out_link.append(new String(ch, start, start + length));
       }
 }

 public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {
    if (elementOn) {
        elementOn = false;
        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase(ID)) {
            sitesList.setId(out_id.toString());
            bool_id = false;
        } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase(LINK)) {
            sitesList.setLink(out_link.toString());
            bool_link= false;
                   }
             }
       }
```

Hope this helps.